# What's the difference between Future and FutureTask in Java?

Tags: java, executorservice, callable, futuretask

Since use `ExecutorService` can `submit` a `Callable` task and return a `Future`, why need to use `FutureTask` to wrap `Callable` task and use the method `execute`? I feel they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In fact you are correct. The two approaches are identical. You generally don't need to wrap them yourself. If you are, you're likely duplicating the code in AbstractExecutorService:

```
/**
 * Returns a <tt>RunnableFuture</tt> for the given callable task.
 *
 * @param callable the callable task being wrapped
 * @return a <tt>RunnableFuture</tt> which when run will call the
 * underlying callable and which, as a <tt>Future</tt>, will yield
 * the callable's result as its result and provide for
 * cancellation of the underlying task.
 * @since 1.6
 */
protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
    return new FutureTask<T>(callable);
}
```

The only difference between Future and RunnableFuture, is the run() method:

```
/**
 * A {@link Future} that is {@link Runnable}. Successful execution of
 * the <tt>run</tt> method causes completion of the <tt>Future</tt>
 * and allows access to its results.
 * @see FutureTask
 * @see Executor
 * @since 1.6
 * @author Doug Lea
 * @param <V> The result type returned by this Future's <tt>get</tt> method
 */
public interface RunnableFuture<V> extends Runnable, Future<V> {
    /**
     * Sets this Future to the result of its computation
     * unless it has been cancelled.
     */
    void run();
}
```

A good reason to let the Executor construct the FutureTask for you is to ensure that there is no possible way more than one reference exists to the FutureTask instance. That is, the Executor *owns* this instance.

Comment: FutureTask.get() never throws a CancellationException, whereas Future.get() does. Is this correct? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).

Answer (score 50):

[FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)
This class provides a `base implementation of Future`, with methods to start and cancel a computation

[Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) is the interface

Answer (score 17):

`Future` is just interface. Behind the scene, the implementation is `FutureTask`.

You can absolutely use `FutureTask` manually but you will lose the advantages of using `Executor` (pooling thread, limit the thread, etc). Using `FutureTask` is quite similar to using the old `Thread` and using the **run** method.

Comment: FutureTask implements both Future<V> and Runnable so why can't it be submitted to ExecutorService?

Comment: I think FutureTask can be submitted to Executor?  "A FutureTask can be used to wrap a Callable or Runnable object. Because FutureTask implements Runnable, a FutureTask can be submitted to an Executor for execution."   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html

Answer (score 8):

You would only need to use FutureTask if you want to change its behaviour or access its Callable later.  For 99% of uses, just use Callable and Future.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark, and others, correctly answered that `Future` is the interface for `FutureTask` and `Executor` effectively its factory; meaning that application code rarely instantiates `FutureTask` directly. To complement the discussion I am providing an example showing a situation where `FutureTask` is constructed and used directly, outside any `Executor`:

```
    FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<Integer>(()-> {
        System.out.println("Pretend that something complicated is computed");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return 42;
    });

    Thread t1 = new Thread(()->{
        try {
            int r = task.get();
            System.out.println("Result is " + r);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {}
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(()->{
        try {
            int r = task.get();
            System.out.println("Result is " + r);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {}
    });
    Thread t3 = new Thread(()->{
        try {
            int r = task.get();
            System.out.println("Result is " + r);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {}
    });

    System.out.println("Several threads are going to wait until computations is ready");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    task.run(); // let the main thread to compute the value
```

Here, `FutureTask` is used as a synchronization tool, like `CountdownLatch` or similar barrier primitive. It could have been re-implemented by using `CountdownLatch` or locks and conditions; `FutureTask` just makes it nicely encapsulated, self-explanatory, elegant and with less code.

Also note that FutureTask#run() method must be called explicitly, in any of the threads; there no Executor around to do it for you. In my code, it is eventually executed by the main thread, but one can modify `get()` method to call `run()` on the first thread calling `get()`, therefore the first thread reaching `get()`, and it can be any of T1, T2 or T3, would do the calculation for all remaining threads.

On this idea - first thread requesting result would do the calculation for others, while concurrent attempts would be blocked - is based Memoizer, see Memoizer Cache example from page 108 in "Java Concurrency in Practice".

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned , but speaking not in general but in more of technical terms, since  FutureTask implements RunnableFuture,
you can call it using

```
FutureTask<T> result = new FutureTask<T>(new #YourClassImplementingCallable());
Thread t1= new Thread(result);
t1.start();
Object<T> obj = result.get();
```

This is more inline with older runnable but it also has the capacity to return result via callback.

The greater power of FutureTask over Future lies in the fact that it has more control over threads as against just simply Submitting a callable to Future and let executor handle the threads.

like you can call here t1.join().