# What are the benefits of wrapping Callable/Runnable in a FutureTask?

Tags: multithreading, java-8, java.util.concurrent, concurrent.futures

What does FutureTask wrapper offer over simple Callable/Runnables?
I've seen some people using futures that way, but I am not sure what it really adds to the game.

```
Callable<Integer> myComputation = () -> {return 0;};
FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<Integer>(myComputation);

//Why this...       
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(task);
task.get();

//...over the conventional approach?
Future<Integer> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(myComputation);
future.get();
```

Comment: There are some more good insights on this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956822/whats-the-difference-between-future-and-futuretask-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no benefits. The only difference in public interface is that `FutureTask` implements `RunnableFuture` which in addition to the `Future` methods allows you to run the task via `RunnableFuture.run()` method, but I doubt that you will need to run it directly.

The main purpose of using the `FutureTask` class directly is the ability to subclass it providing custom implementation for some protected methods like `done()` or `setException()`. So it would make sense in the following piece of code:

```
Callable<Integer> myComputation = () -> {return 0;};
FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<Integer>(myComputation) {
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // some custom action on task completion
    }
};
```

Comment: Wrapping manually is required when you only have an `Executor` instead of `ExecutorService`. Or if you want to be able to cancel your own task from within the actual action.